# How can I host Office add-ins on localhost?

Tags: windows, iis, webserver, ms-office, office-addins

I'm new to web-servers. I have Internet Information Services (IIS) 10 Express installed on Windows 10. I'm trying to develop an Office add-in so as to host it in the same computer I use. The problem is how do I host the add-in in a local web server? Since I'm new would appreciate a little of step by step answer.

Answer (score 0):

while you are developing the add-in, you do not need to worry about a local web server. The Visual Studio tools take care of all that for you (it will run in a web server provided by Visual Studio).

If you are using Visual Studio 2015 (the [community edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) is free and works fine with Office add-ins), you simply create a new 'office add-in' project and it will all be set up for you. It will create a 'web project' for you and it will use that web project when you run the application locally - you do not need to do anything to make that happen.

You may find that you have to install the Office tools for Visual Studio but if you go to File > New > Project > Visual C# > Office/SharePoint you'll get a link to download the tools if you do not already have them.

In terms of hosting it in the public domain, I like to use the [Azure Web App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/web/) service as you can very easily publish directly from Visual Studio or you can setup continuous integration with GitHub, VSO etc. Once you have it hosted in the public domain, you simply change the 'Source Location' in your office add-in manifest file to point at your public URL.

Comment: My problem is when using a different editor/IDE other than Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code.

Comment: If you are using windows 10, by far the best experience is going to be with visual studio. You can get Visual studio 2015 community edition completely free of charge and it does everything you need for developing office add-ins. If you still do not want to use visual studio, it will depend how you are writing your web app. If it is just flat html, Js, css, you do not need a webserver, just point the source location at the local file path of you index.html file. If you are using something else, please add details

Comment: Yes, I'm using flat html, Js, CSS, and of course the Manifest.xml file that is needed. I did not thought of having the index.html file, as such was pointing to my home.html instead and it never worked. Every time I tried Excel would complain of not finding the home.html file even when in Manifest.xml was clearly pointed to. I could not find a simple example of such use case to follow.

Comment: If you do a file>new project>office>office addin, this default template is exactly the setup you are describing. I think it uses a relative path from the solution root to whatever html file is the starting point for the app. Just copy that and overwrite that default web project where necessary as it has all the right references and 'plunbing code' for an addin.

Comment: @MartinKearn `window.open('about:blank')` method is not working in my `Office.js WORD add-in`. I've posted the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53027657/1232087). Would you have any suggestion?

Comment: But how do I host using a local web server?

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured it out.

Except it broke my VS Setup now (Resolved)--> See here [Installing IIS broke Visual Studio Office Add In Project Localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70635789/5079799)

To enable IIS I had to open "Programs and Features" and select "Internet Information Systems".

Then start --> IIS. Browse to default site and added binding for SSL/Port 44367 (Same as VS). I already had a SSL cert from previous configurations, selecting the Dev Cert worked fine.

I copied everything from `\ExcelWebAddIn1\ExcelWebAddIn1Web\*` to the webroot `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` and adjusted the following in manifest.

replace:

`~remoteAppUrl`

with

`https://localhost:44367`

I then sideloaded the manifest and it worked as expected.

Note that [Martin Kearn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34836496/5079799) still applies, this isn't needed if you want to just use VS and it has better debugging, but I wanted to test and learn.

This was all to test/debug deployment, and I was able to do the same by just changing the localhost url to a simple nginx webserver w/ the contents of the above webroot.