# Installing IIS broke Visual Studio Office Add In Project Localhost

Tags: visual-studio, iis, office-addins

I was trying to answer this question "How to host Office Add In with IIS" --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/70616170/5079799 and I did by installing IIS and configuring it to serve site.

It seemed to work fine then, switching between IIS and VS, but after perhaps a reboot or regardless, today, I can't seem to get VS to use its own webserver. It seems to be serving the files under IIS webroot `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`, not the files in the project as I can navigate to URLs in my webroot, but if I open IIS, it doesn't show running.

Any ideas?

Update:

- I tried completely uninstalling IIS from Programs and Features, but VS (2017) still seems to serve the webroot vs the project files.
- Shortly after, VS didn't seem to load anything, neither the project, or the webroot was available after running solution
- It seems URL/Ports have been changed somehow in the settings under my vbprojec files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found some settings that VS seems to have changed on me and one setting I changed that messed everything up.

I had hard coded the --> `~remoteAppUrl/` to be `localhost:port`.

I did manage to get things to work, two times, but adjusting settings, but I couldn't reliably reproduce so I did a hard reset and tried adjusting the `localhost:port` to `~remoteAppUrl/` in the xml and it worked, using a different port then before. This is probably the best route to go as I had already created a "localhost" xml and a prod xml so I can leave the VS xml with `~remoteAppUrl/`. I'm guessing VS noticed that IIS was using the port it had before, even though IIS was off, it decided to use a new port to avoid conflict?

Here is some settings I changed to get it to work:

In Web.vbproj

```
<IISExpressSSLPort>44342</IISExpressSSLPort>

<AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>

<DevelopmentServerPort>57161</DevelopmentServerPort>

<IISUrl>http://localhost:57161/</IISUrl>
```

Became:

```
<IISExpressSSLPort>44367</IISExpressSSLPort>

<AutoAssignPort>False</AutoAssignPort>

<DevelopmentServerPort>44367</DevelopmentServerPort>

<IISUrl>https://localhost:44367/</IISUrl>
```

In Web.vbproj.user:

```
<IISExpressSSLPort>44367</IISExpressSSLPort>
```

Also I noticed that my GUID had changed somewhere along the line, so make sure that all lines up.

I also changed the URL in the Web Properties.

[image]

Viewing the properties gave me some insight as well.

[image]